# Are the anniversary event Pikachu permanent?

Tags: pokemon-go

All Pikachu in the wild will be wearing Ash's hat. Will we be able to keep these after the event?

I know there was a similar event for Christmas, were those hats permanent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can keep and even evolve them without losing the hats. You just can't catch any new ones after the event has ended.

The [Official Twitter account](https://twitter.com/PokemonGoApp/status/809204696812392448) confirmed you keep the hats from previous events, so it's highly unlikely to lose them this time.

> Raichu evolved from #HolidayPikachu will be wearing a festive hat.
>   Both Pokémon will also keep the hat permanently!

Comment: It's not about this event, yet you call it a source.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I included a reason why I used this as a source. It's highly unlikely (almost impossible) this event is different from any other special hat event or do you think everyone loses their hats now just because Niantic hates us?

Comment: It is not a source, and should not be called such.